# CRM 4.0 ISV page under CRM 2011 not showing correct user

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have a simple ISV page (using 2007 service endpoints, 4.0 SDK) that only shows the Identity of a user who has opened it.

`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`

This page in CRM 4.0 shows a valid user **DOMAIN\USERNAME**

When this page is deployed to CRM 2011 it only shows **NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE**

The CRM 2011 has a Claims Based authentication configured together with IFD. There is a STS server and Credentials. All connections seem work fine. The page is accessed via: https://servername.domain.com/organization/main.aspx and in an intranet environment.

It just looks that the page can not pickup the identity of a user who has opened it.

Have you experienced this before? Is there something not configured correctly?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure what user is logged on you can use [WhoAmI message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb890244.aspx). In that way you are able retrieve full information about the user.
Also ASP.Net provide a way to retrieve currently logged in user [HttpContext.User Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx). But it could contains different values, depending on [Authentication Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334502.aspx). In case of IFD with claims-based authentication, HttpContext.User will contains id of SystemUser entity.